# MYSQL query to get monthly consumption data from table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, time-series, energy

I have a table 'consumption' in mysql with around 5 million records like:

```
month from  |   month to         |       consumption
2012-12-20     2013-01-10                  200
2013-01-11     2013-02-13                  345
```

Is there a way to get the consumption for each month like:
consumption for January(2013-01-01 to 2013-01-31)  = ..., for February = .... The value can be an estimated figure, need not be perfect.

I thought of taking the average consumption per day multiplying it with the number of days for the month  for different date ranges, but not sure how to go with it.

Update:

@Karolis Using the original excel formula,  I am getting an estimated  consumption value that is higher than the value computed using the sql script. As far as I know both the sql script and excel formula is doing the same computation. Can you please help me in finding out why this is happening and making the sql script consumption value same as the one obtained using excel.

Original Table:

```
            id  month_from  month_to    consumption 
            121 2009-12-30  2009-01-28  1251            <-First period
            121 2010-01-29  2010-02-24  915             <-Second period
            993 xxxx-xx-xx  xxxx-xx-xx  xxx 
            121 2010-02-25  2010-03-25  741 
            121 2010-03-26  2010-04-28  1508
```

I Used the script you had given, made a slight modification and added a group by id and order by id, the script I am using is:

```
SELECT 
    m.month, id, 
    SUM(
        -- partial consumption = date subrange / date range * consumption
        (
            DATEDIFF(
                IF(c.date_to > m.last_day, m.last_day, c.date_to),
                IF(c.date_from < m.first_day, m.first_day, c.date_from)
            ) + 1
        ) / (DATEDIFF(c.date_to, c.date_from) + 1) * c.consumption
    ) consumption
FROM
    consumption c
    JOIN (
        -- series of months
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            DATE_FORMAT(date_from, '%Y %M') month,
            DATE_FORMAT(date_from, '%Y-%m-01') first_day,
            LAST_DAY(date_from) last_day
        FROM consumption
        GROUP BY date_from -- redundant, but for speed purposes
    ) m ON 
        -- condition indicating a date range belongs to a particular 
        -- month (fully or partially)
        c.date_from <= m.last_day AND c.date_to >= m.first_day
   GROUP BY m.month, id
   ORDER BY m.month, id
```

Excel formula:

```
if((idInCurrentLine = idInNextLine), ((((month_to - start_date) + 1  )*consumptionPerDayForFirstPeriod/day ) + (start_date - month_from) *  consumptionPerDayForsecondPeriod/day), "")

consumptionPerDayForFirstPeriod = consumptionFortheFirstPeriod/((month_to - month_from)+ 1)
consumptionPerDayForSecondPeriod = consumptinoFortheSecondPeriod/((month_to - month_from)+ 1)
```

In the example given

```
idInCurrentLine = 121, idInNextLine = 121
```

Using these two I calculated estimated consumption and result is :

Estimated Consumption: (As you can see there is a difference in estimated value in both cases, with the estimation using excel higher than sql.

```
             Month           Using Excel    Using mysql script
             2009 january    1313.4         1269.3  
             2009 Febuary    950.47         915.5   
             2009 March      935.78         904..9  
             xxxx            xxxx           xxxxx   
             xxxx            xxxx           xxxxx
```

Comment: Who upvotes this stuff?

Comment: @Strawberry Oh c'mon, it's a very good and quite complicated question.

Comment: @Karolis I don't think so. At a minimum, I think a good question would provide a properly representative data set (ideally as a set of DDLs), and a corresponding result set.

Comment: @Strawberry While the wording of the question may not be perfect, the main task is quite understandable :)

Comment: @Karolis Let's agree to disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    m.month,
    SUM(
        -- partial consumption = date subrange / date range * consumption
        (
            DATEDIFF(
                IF(c.month_to > m.last_day, m.last_day, c.month_to),
                IF(c.month_from < m.first_day, m.first_day, c.month_from)
            ) + 1
        ) / (DATEDIFF(c.month_to, c.month_from) + 1) * c.consumption
    ) consumption
FROM
    consumption c
    JOIN (
        -- series of months
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            DATE_FORMAT(month_from, '%Y %M') month,
            DATE_FORMAT(month_from, '%Y-%m-01') first_day,
            LAST_DAY(month_from) last_day
        FROM consumption
        GROUP BY month_from -- redundant, but for speed purposes
    ) m ON 
        -- condition indicating that a date range belongs
        -- to a particular month (fully or partially)
        c.month_from <= m.last_day AND c.month_to >= m.first_day
GROUP BY m.first_day
ORDER BY m.first_day
```

Comment: I have updated the post, could you please check it and tell me why this is happening. I am held up with issue for sometime now and I do not understand why this is happening. Thank you.

Comment: @RahulNair Is it possible that your date fields (in Excel or Mysql) actually are date/time fields? Because `2009-10-11` is not the same as `2009-10-11 14:30:16`.

Comment: I think it was my mistake , there was an error in the excel formula, apologize for that and thank you once again for helping me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Datediff is your friend - try `consumption * 30 / Datediff(day, monthfrom, monthto)`

Answer (score -2):

in short, you would use BETWEEN:

```
SELECT consumption from [table] where [input date] is between [monthFrom] and [monthTo]
```

Where your input date is the area within the range.

Comment: Hi, I want the consumption data from one month, not for a particular day,for example, consumption for January is equal to ____ this much..With this query wouldn't I only get the result for a particular day?

Comment: Not exactly.  Your input date could just as easily be another date field that shows activity.  The point of the answer is to show how the BETWEEN function works.  And phooie on whoever gave the downvote!